# SqlDataReader in ASP.NET deallocation and close

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sqldatareader

Does the following code, cleanup all SqlDataReaders correctly:

```
using (IDataReader reader = SqlHelper.GetDataReader(sql.ToString())) {
    if (reader.Read()) {
        result = reader.IsDBNull(0) ? string.Empty : reader[0].ToString();
    }
}
```

I have some concurrency/deallocation issues in my code and trying to hunt them down.

Comment: where do you capture the concurrency/deallocation issue, is there any stack strace ?

Answer (score 2):

`Dispose()` will be called on the `IDataReader` automatically, once the end of the `using` statement goes out of scope. Also make sure that the reader is created with the `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` so that the reader will dispose of the connection once it is disposed.

But I don't see any other code involving the connection. If you are using the classic `SqlHelper` class, that maybe the source of the issue...